# Cocos2D-Python to Android/iOS

Tags: android, ios, python-3.5, cocos2d-python

I have a feeling this question must have been asked elsewhere but I still can't figure this out. My question is two-fold:

1. Can Cocos2D-Python be used to create games for both iOS AND Android?
   Or am I stuck with Cocos2D-x with I'm looking for that
   cross-platform feature?
2. (Depending on the answer to #1) Do I have to install Android studio, Xcode and any other relevant IDEs to do the job? I'm asking this because I personally enjoy working with just text editors and command prompt.

Although I have no problem with switching to Cocos2D-x, I'd like to know what my options are before I make the commitment because Python is the only language I know right now. I am using 64-bit Windows 10.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Based on the info at [cocos2d](http://cocos2d.org/#cocos2dpy) homepage cocos2d-python only supports Mac, Win and Linux and not ios/android. Cocos2dx however supports mobile versions as well but it uses c++

2) You can work entirely on using the `cocos` cli which comes bundled when you install cocos2dx so you don't need to install any IDEs. Personally I used nvim so pretty much any editor works.

Comment: Thank you. I should've figured "It works on Windows, Linux and Mac" meant it wouldn't work on mobile. I was actually looking around Cocos2d-x documentation to see what I should do, and realized that, while it's focused on C++ it also has examples in Javascript. Their website also mentions that it supports C++, Javascript, and Lua. Would it be worth my time to go learn Javascript? Or would I be better off studying C++?

Comment: It really depends on what kind of programs you want to be developing for. If you want to get into gaming knowing c++ is important since most game engines have frameworks written in c++. On the other hand js is more of a web specific language.Also it is 'closer' to python as compared to C++ so you'll find it easier to learn.

Comment: Got it, C++ it is. Thank you!